# C# String builder, displaying data nicely spaced out

Tags: c#

I am wondering how exactly can i order my date nicely in a stringbuilder?
Meaning something equal to ("{0,2}", ....) to space the data nicely out.
I do not want to use consolewrites of any kind, so the class can be re-used in a form, console code etc...

Currently i am using "   "  for the spacing, but in overall it does not give a proper display. 
(it messed up when i have numbers with more then 1 digit)

```
public override string ToString() 
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int value in tabel)
        {
            builder.Append(value); // should have something similiar to ("{0,2}", ....)
            builder.Append("  "); // should have something similiar to ("{0,2}", ....)
        }

        builder.Append("(top:");
        builder.Append(top);
        builder.Append(")");

        return builder.ToString();
    }/*ToString*/
```

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use AppendFormat, eg:

```
builder.AppendFormat("{0}  ", value);
```

or

```
builder.AppendFormat("{0}  {1}  {2}", value.property1, value.property2, value.property3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting. This example will put 3 places for each number, even for less-digit numbers.

```
value.ToString("000");
```